# Matrix identityJavascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have my Matrix object and am trying to pass a jasmine test with it.

This is the test my matrix object should pass,

```
describe("Create Identity", function () {
    var matrix = Matrix.createIdentity();
    it("Element (0,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 0)).toEqual(1);
    });

    it("Element (0,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 1)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (0,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 2)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (1,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 0)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (1,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 1)).toEqual(1);
    });

    it("Element (1,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 2)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 0)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 1)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 2)).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

My Matrix object:

```
var Matrix = (function () {
function Matrix(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {

    this.arrayMatrix = [
        [pX0, pX1, pX2],
        [pY0, pY1, pY2],
        [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];
}
Matrix.prototype.getX0 = function () {
    return this.mX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX0 = function (pX0) {
    this.mX0 = pX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX1 = function () {
    return this.mX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX1 = function (pX1) {
    this.mX1 = pX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX2 = function () {
    return this.mX2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX2 = function (pX2) {
    this.mX2 = pX2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getY0 = function () {
    return this.mY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY0 = function (pY0) {
    this.mY0 = pY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY1 = function () {
    return this.mY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY1 = function (pY1) {
    this.mY1 = pY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY2 = function () {
    return this.mY2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY2 = function (pY2) {
    this.mY2 = pY2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getZ0 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ0 = function (pZ0) {
    this.mZ0 = pZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ1 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ1 = function (pZ1) {
    this.mZ1 = pZ1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ2 = function () {
    return this.mZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ2 = function (pZ2) {
    this.mZ2 = pZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.getElement = function (pRow, pColumn) {
    return this.arrayMatrix[pRow][pColumn];
};
Matrix.createIdentity = function () {
    var SecMatrix = new Matrix();
    return new SecMatrix([
        1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1
    ]
        );
};
return Matrix;

}());
```

I am struggling to see why this is not passing the test.

This is the brief on how it should be made,

"your Matrix object should have a ‘createIdentity’ function that takes no parameters. The function should return a newly constructed Matrix object that has its cells set to an identity matrix. This function should act like a static method in C#. To do this in your JavaScript object, don’t add the function to the Matrix prototype, but rather to the Matrix object directly. (e.g. Matrix.createIdentity = function() { etc.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

secMatrix is an object and its wrong to get instance of an object

and also you passed an array to constructor instead of parameters

so change the method to this

```
Matrix.createIdentity = function () {
    return new Matrix(
        1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1
        );
};
```